# How to change all columns data types in StructType or ArrayType columns?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame including some columns with `StructType` and `ArrayType`. I want to cast all `IntegerType` columns to `DoubleType`. I found some solutions for this problem. For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60391887/6645617) does the thing similar to what I want. But the problem is, it does not change the data types of columns that are nested in a `StructType` or `ArrayType` column.

For example I have a DataFrame with below schema:

```text
 |-- carCategories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- payerId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- percentage: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- plateNumberStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ratio: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- max: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- min: integer (nullable = true)
```

After executing below script:

```scala
val doubleSchema = df.schema.fields.map{f =>
  f match{
    case StructField(name:String, _:IntegerType, _, _) => col(name).cast(DoubleType)
    case _ => col(f.name)
  }
}

df.select(doubleSchema:_*).printSchema
```

It turns out like this:

```text
 |-- carCategories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- payerId: double (nullable = true)
 |-- percentage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- plateNumberStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ratio: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- max: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- min: integer (nullable = true)
```

As you can see some columns are converted to `DoubleType`, but the columns that are in `ArrayType` and `StructType` are not converted.

I want final schema be like this:

```text
|-- carCategories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- payerId: double (nullable = true)
 |-- percentage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- plateNumberStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ratio: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- max: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- min: double (nullable = true)
```

How can I achieve such a thing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add case clauses to handle `ArrayType` and `StructType` like this:

```scala
def castIntToDouble(schema: StructType): Seq[Column] = {
  schema.fields.map { f =>
    f.dataType match {
      case IntegerType => col(f.name).cast(DoubleType)
      case StructType(_) =>
        col(f.name).cast(
          f.dataType.simpleString.replace(s":${IntegerType.simpleString}", s":${DoubleType.simpleString}")
        )
      case dt: ArrayType =>
        dt.elementType match {
          case IntegerType => col(f.name).cast(ArrayType(DoubleType))
          case StructType(_) =>
            col(f.name).cast(
              f.dataType.simpleString.replace(s":${IntegerType.simpleString}",s":${DoubleType.simpleString}")
            )
          case _ => col(f.name)
        }
      case _ => col(f.name)
    }
  }
}
```

The function uses casting with `DLL` strings format when the type of column is `StructType` or array of nested structs. e.g. if you have to cast the struct column `ratio` which has type `struct<max:int,min:int>` without having to recreate the the whole struct you'd do:

```scala
df.withColumn("ratio", col("ratio").cast("struct<max:double,min:double>"))
```

Now applying this to your input example:

```scala
val df = (
   Seq((Seq(1, 2, 3), 34, 87, "pending", (65, 22)))
  .toDF("carCategories","payerId","percentage","plateNumberStatus","ratio")
  .withColumn("ratio", col("ratio").cast("struct<max:int,min:int>"))
)

df.select(castIntToDouble(df.schema):_*).printSchema
//root
// |-- carCategories: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
// |-- payerId: double (nullable = false)
// |-- percentage: double (nullable = false)
// |-- plateNumberStatus: string (nullable = true)
// |-- ratio: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- max: double (nullable = true)
// |    |-- min: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop . your answer works like a charm on the sample you and I provided. But when I apply this function on the whole DataFarme with its full schema, I get a weird error. and I don't know what causes this error: `scala.MatchError: StringType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$)`. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks.

Comment: @AliAzG probably coming from type array of strings. This was missing from the case clause of ArrayType `case _ => col(f.name)`. I added it into the above function. can you try again?